# allure report custom plugins

Tags: maven, testng, allure

I have integrated the allure report successfully into our Selenium tests with TestNG. Using [this](https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example) as an example.

I am now looking into adding some of our own custom tabs onto the report and looking at [allure-report-plugins](https://github.com/baev/allure-report-plugins) as examples I can see how simple plugins can be created, however how do I integrate these example plugins into our existing report.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you ever found a solution but for anyone who finds this via google the answer is to edit the `allure.yml` file which can be found in the config directory of your allure install 
e.g `C:\Windows\Program Files\Allure\config\allure.yml`

Open the file with a text editor and add the following to the end of the line to enable the custom logo plugin:

`- custom-logo-plugin`

The dash and space at the start are required

Comment: Where should .jar file with this custom-logo-plugin be put?

Comment: .jar should be put in allure\plugins\custom-logo-plugin